# How to test negative scenario for below component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How to test negative scenario forbelow compoent:

javascript:

```
  selectedData:function(cmp,pageNumber, pageSize){
    var action = cmp.get("c.NextPagination");
    var ListOfUsr=cmp.get("v.LstOfAddedUser");
    var LstId=cmp.get("v.LstOfAddedUser");
    if(LstId!=null && LstId.length>0){
        action.setParams({
            "selectedIds":JSON.stringify(cmp.get("v.LstOfAddedUser").map(thisItem => thisItem.Id)),
            "pageNumber": pageNumber,
            "pageSize": pageSize,
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state ==="SUCCESS")
            {
                var resultData = response.getReturnValue();
                if(resultData!=null){
                    cmp.set("v.UserdataList", resultData.userdataList);
                    cmp.set("v.PageNumber", resultData.pageNumber);
                    cmp.set("v.TotalRecords", resultData.totalRecords);
                    cmp.set("v.RecordStart", resultData.recordStart);
                    cmp.set("v.RecordEnd", resultData.recordEnd);
                    cmp.set("v.TotalPages", Math.ceil(resultData.totalRecords / pageSize));    
                }

            } 
            else if(state === "ERROR"){
                var errors = action.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                        if(!toastEvent){
                            //If the toastEvent is not there, it's because we are working with Lightning Out.
                            //So use a custom message container
                            var severity = 'Error'; 
                            var title = '';
                            var message = errors[0].message;
                            var messageContainer = cmp.find("messageContainer");
                            messageContainer.displayMessage(severity,title,message);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

Js:

```
  @AuraEnabled
  public static UserDataTableWrapper NextPagination(string 
 selectedIds,Decimal 
  pageNumber, Decimal pageSize){//name:change
 try{
    List<String> lstSelectedIds = 
    (List<String>)System.JSON.deserialize(selectedIds, List<String>.class);
    Integer pSize = (Integer)pageSize;
    Integer pNumber = (Integer)pageNumber;
    Integer offset = (pNumber - 1) * pSize;
    Integer totalRecords =lstSelectedIds.size();
    Integer recordEnd = pSize * pNumber;
    //Instance of Contact DataTable Wrapper Class
    UserDataTableWrapper objDT = new UserDataTableWrapper();  
    objDT.pageSize = pSize;
    objDT.pageNumber = pNumber;
    objDT.recordStart = offset + 1;
    objDT.recordEnd = totalRecords >= recordEnd ? recordEnd : totalRecords;
    objDT.totalRecords = totalRecords;
    objDT.userdataList = [SELECT Id, Name,User__c,User__r.Name FROM 
  GSS_User_Data__c where id=:lstSelectedIds ORDER BY Name LIMIT :pSize 
   OFFSET :offset];
    system.debug(' objDT.userdataList---->'+objDT.userdataList);
    return objDT;
   }catch(exception ex){
  throw new AuraHandledException('Please contact your salesforce adminstrator for more Information');
```

}
    }

I would like to test negative scenarios as well. How can I show below error message in my componet. I had written in my component side.

```
Please contact your salesforce adminstrator for more Information
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This query will never throw a `QueryException`

```
try{
    User currentUser = [select id,FirstName FROM User Where id =:userInfo.getUserId()];
    return currentUser;
}
```

because there never isn't a running user - i.e., this query will always match exactly one record.

You should simply remove the exception handler because there is no catchable exception that could be thrown here.

Comment: sorry .updated the question

Comment: @SFDCFAN You seem to have changed your question into a completely different one, thus invalidating my answer. That is quite frustrating.